# How to login into joomla backend without reauthenticated when already logged in frontend?

Tags: php, joomla, single-sign-on, joomla3.0

I am already logged in the front end of my joomla site with admin credentials. But when I try to login into the backend or admin panel it ask me to renter credentials. I want that when a user is logged in the front end and if he has the access capabilities to login into admin panel then he should be directly logged into admin panel without asking for credentials.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible by default in Joomla like WordPress. Back-end and Front-end are separated in Joomla. So you need to login separately in both section for security. However you can use third party extensions. Try the following extensions

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-security/login-one

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/ev-front-end-admin-navigation

Before start using them, read the reviews and ratings. Also make sure, you don't have security issues in your site by using these extensions.

Answer (score 0):

There are two plugins in JED that can help you:
1. http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/ev-front-end-admin-navigation

2. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-access/auto-front-end-login

Basically when admin logs in frontend it simultaneously creates a backend session. Not difficult and can be easily done through a plugin.